# Extended Qgis Web Client - (gisapp) Helloworld Project Setup on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: qgis, web, client

I have a problem setting up the Helloworld Project to load in a browser. All QGIS server settings are working including 'GetCapabilities' requests etc. When I click on the test url:

http://localhost/gisapp/helloworld?public=on

I get:

The requested URL /gisapp/helloworld was not found on this server.

Apache2 log:-

```
[Fri Nov 13 19:22:04.470964 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1102] AH00163: Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu) SVN/1.8.13 mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Nov 13 19:22:04.471044 2015] [core:notice] [pid 1102] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Nov 13 19:37:20.277608 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1102] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Nov 13 19:37:21.410392 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3915] AH00163: Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu) SVN/1.8.13 mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Nov 13 19:37:21.410448 2015] [core:notice] [pid 3915] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Nov 13 19:56:04.745097 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3915] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Nov 13 19:56:05.866559 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4225] AH00163: Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu) SVN/1.8.13 mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Nov 13 19:56:05.866616 2015] [core:notice] [pid 4225] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

"/var/log/apache2/error.log" 8L, 1053C
```

Comment: I don't think this is your problem. The log messages are looking normal see here http://serverfault.com/questions/607873/apache-is-ok-but-what-is-this-in-error-log-mpm-preforknotice